# Double line of buttons in jqGrid pager

Tags: jquery, button, jqgrid, pager

I have a problem with the layout of my page.  I have filled out all the free space on the page and the buttons merge with the navigation bar. I need to have at least two lines to add more buttons.

I'm looking for something like this:

[image: PHOTO]

Pager (Navigation bar)

button 1 button 2 button 3 .......... page 1 to 4 ............ records 10 of 35
button 4 button 5 button 6

This is the code where I am adding the buttons:

```
.navGrid('#pager_list') {..}
.navButtonAdd('#pager_list', {
    id:"btnResumen",
    caption:"Resumen",
    title: "Resumen de errores",
    buttonicon:"ui-icon-mail-closed",
    onClickButton: function(e) {
        bajarResumen();
    },
    position:"last"
})
.navButtonAdd('#pager_list', {
    caption:"A texto",
    title: "Bajar y enviar x mail",
    buttonicon:"ui-icon-mail-closed",
    onClickButton: function(e) {
        bajarATexto("Enviando...");
    },
    position:"last"
});
```

Comment: You can include URL to the image and other can include it. You can include JavaScript code which shows what you do.

Comment: where can i share the image?

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand you. If I type in Google words "share image" I see suggestion "share image online". If I choose the suggestion I get the list of URLs where http://tinypic.com/ is the first one. You can choose the place or search for your question in Google.

Comment: yeah, thank you i think was "upload an image" i haven't a good english!! jejej here is the link
https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/547233_10200725182439396_1686115628_n.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i can just use css to do that:

```
<style type="text/css">
     .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-pager .ui-pg-button{
        display: inline;
        float:left;
    }
    .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-pager{
        height: auto;
    }
</style>
```

Or if you want to do that in a specific grig you can do:

```
 <style type="text/css">
     .ui-jqgrid #yourGridID.ui-jqgrid-pager .ui-pg-button{
        display: inline;
        float:left;
    }
    .ui-jqgrid #yourGridID.ui-jqgrid-pager{
        height: auto;
    }
</style>
```

hope that helps!